# PowerShell export to csv. Only quote 1 set in each row

Tags: powershell, csv, exchange-server, double-quotes

When I'm building a CSV Export it puts quotes around every set of parameters.  However, I only want 1 set to have the quotes.

```powershell
$UserInfo = New-Object System.Object
foreach ($user in $MailBoxList)
{
  $UserInfo | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name LegacyExchangeDN -Value $user.LegacyExchangeDN
  $UserInfo | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name CloudEmailAddress -Value $CloudEmailAddress
  $UserInfo | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name OnPremiseEmailAddress -Value $user.PrimarySMTPAddress.ToString()
  $UserInfo | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name MailboxGUID -Value $user.ExchangeGUID

  $Users += $UserInfo
}

$Users | Export-CSV -Delimiter "," -Path ".\cloud.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

This code results in this exported CSV:

```
"LegacyExchangeDN","CloudEmailAddress","OnPremiseEmailAddress","MailboxGUID"
"/o=MyUnit/ou=This Admin Group (BRBIDOMF87SRQLT)/cn=Recipients/cn=a0dd27c5djd864108cfa61dj37dj56c6-MyLastName, M","mMyLastName@WhereverImFrom.Bob.com","mMyLastName@AnotherDomain.com","687efe5e-4690-110e-86a5-69fr4cdecf7e"
```

What I'd like is just the first column of data to have double quotes and the rest without:

```
"/o=MyUnit/ou=This Admin Group (BRBIDOMF87SRQLT)/cn=Recipients/cn=a0dd27c5djd864108cfa61dj37dj56c6-MyLastName, M",mMyLastName@WhereverImFrom.Bob.com,mMyLastName@AnotherDomain.com,687efe5e-4690-110e-86a5-69fr4cdecf7e
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why is having quotes around all of your values a problem? It will be *far* easier to work with data in that form in the future, and it's consistent with expected CSV output.

Comment: @alroc, CSV allows unquoted values in fields as well. Only values containing the separator, line breaks or quotes need to be quoted. That being said, PowerShell's behaviour isn't wrong and shouldn't cause any problems with applications that support CSV properly.

Comment: I didn't say that CSV didn't allow unquoted values. What I'm saying is that having your values quoted *inconsistently* seems like asking for trouble in the future, and should be unnecessary. PowerShell's behavior (to quote all values by default) results in the least possible surprises later.

Comment: I agree 100% with your assessment.  However, when using the CSV to import the data so I can convert 0365 mailboxes to mail enabled user, when exporting the CSV to Exchange 2003, it's reading the quotes as a character for the second and remaining columns.  Weird, I know, but in 2007 the quotes around every column work perfectly.  I have to have them in the first column because of the comma separating the lastname and firstname.

Comment: General comment: Any idea why it's only pulling back the first 128 characters for the LegacyExchangeDN value ? Is there a way to increase this? The first field is getting truncated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can "roll your own" csv file:

```
$Outfile = ".\cloud.csv"
'LegacyExchangeDN,CloudEmailAddress,OnPremiseEmailAddress' | Set-Content $Outfile

foreach($user in $MailBoxList)
{
  $Data = @(
             $user.LegacyExchangeDN,
             $CloudEmailAddress,
             $user.PrimarySMTPAddress.ToString()
            )

 '"{0}",{1},{2}' -f $Data | Add-Content $Outfile
}
```

Comment: This is a great solution and easy to maintain.  Thanks for the quick response.  I'd up-vote your answer but I don't have enough rep.

Comment: General comment: Any idea why it's only pulling back the first 128 characters? Is there a way to increase this? The first field is getting truncated

Comment: Are you sure it's actually truncated in the file, and not just on the console output?

Comment: Yea, here's another example in the CSV file:

Comment: "/o=ExchangeLabs/ou=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDRBOHDK38PDLT)/cn=Recipients/cn=RG1187638c964929rcw706a28763d41c-Owens, Chri"  You can see the first name is definitely truncated.

Comment: And it's not truncated in the input csv?

Comment: No, it's truncated there too.  It's like it's only pulling or storing the first 128 characters in the variable. I've even stepped through the powershell, and did an output of the value right after it's pulled from O365.

Comment: I'd start a new question on that.  May be an O365 thing, but whatever it is, it's not related to the question of how to construct a csv file with selectively quoted field data.

Comment: @DougPunchak Well, if it's truncated in the input CSV, then the GIGO principle applies. ;) But then, it's not a problem with this PowerShell script, it's a problem with the export mechanism. Unless you're also using a script for that, the question probably belongs at [sf] rather than Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution. What it does is convert the objects to csv-strings and then modify them before saving the csv to a file.

```
foreach($user in $MailBoxList)
{
    $UserInfo = New-Object System.Object
    $UserInfo | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name LegacyExchangeDN -Value $user.LegacyExchangeDN
    $UserInfo | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name CloudEmailAddress -Value $CloudEmailAddress
    $UserInfo | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name OnPremiseEmailAddress -Value 
    $user.PrimarySMTPAddress.ToString()

    $UserInfo | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name MailboxGUID -Value $user.ExchangeGUID

    $Users += $UserInfo

}

#Convert to csv-formatted-strings
$csv = $Users | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ","

#Get header
$out = @($csv[0])

#Remove quotes for all but first column
$out += $csv[1..($csv.Length-1)] | % {

    [regex]::Match($_,'(^"[^"]*",)(.*)') | % { "{0}{1}" -f $_.Groups[1], $_.Groups[2].Value.Replace('"',"") }

}

$out | Set-Content -Path ".\cloud.csv"
```

Another apporach without regex:

```
#Remove quotes for all but first column
$out += $csv[1..($csv.Length-1)] | % {

    $values = $_ -split '","'
    $values[0] + '"' + $values[1..($values.Length-1)] -join ','

}
```

Comment: Your regular expression is very impressive and this solution works perfectly!  However, I'm not familiar with the regex syntax so maintenance going forward may be a challenge.

Comment: General comment: Any idea why it's only pulling back the first 128 characters?  Is there a way to increase this?  The first field is getting truncated.

Comment: True. I added a different apporach. Personally, I would have created my own csv like mjolinor showed, but that's the obvious way, so I wanted to show an alternative :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying in your second comment.

Comment: Frode, thanks again for the quick response.  Check out the comment stream in the other answer above.  The first column of values, the one you helped me get in double-quotes, is being truncated at 128 characters when I know its larger than 128.

Comment: What happends if you write `Write-host $user.LegacyExchangeDN` inside the user-loop? Just to verify if it's the data itself is truncated.

Comment: They're truncated there too.  Should I make this a new question?

Comment: Yes. Remember to include the code that creates `$MailBoxList`.